# Тестирование в Laravel

Tags: php, ubuntu, laravel, тестирование, vagrant

Есть два условно независимых проекта. Один основной, второй - админка от первого. Админка построена на базе Laravel 5.4, основной сайт написан вручную, с использованием некоторых компонентов Laravel, но без самого Laravel. Возникла необходимость написать тесты для всего этого дела. И было принято решение поюзать Laravel админки для тестирования роутов и админки, и основного сайта. Условно назовём админку `http://admin.dev`, основной сайт - `http://project.dev`. Под Vagrant'ом в `/etc/hosts` оба домена смотрят на `127.0.0.1`, на локальной машине оба домена смотрят на IP Vagrant'а. Пробую запускать следующий код:

```
namespace Tests\Feature;

use Tests\TestCase;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\WithoutMiddleware;

class ProjectRoutesTest extends TestCase
{
    /**
     * A basic test example.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function testExample()
    {
      // $response = $this->get( 'http://project.dev' );
      // $response = $this->get( 'project.dev' );
      // $response = $this->get( 'https://ya.ru' );
      $response = $this->call( 'GET', '/', [], [], [], ['SERVER_NAME' => 'project.dev'] );

      $response->assertStatus(200);
    }
}
```

Закомментированные учатки нарочно оставил, чтобы было видно что я уже попробовал. То есть я, условно говоря, пробовал запрашивать не только домен основного проекта, но и Яндекс, и гугл, и саму админку, и отовсюду мне приходит статус `302` вместо ожидаемого `200`. Кто виноват? Vagrant? В какую сторону вообще смотреть?

Ubuntu 17.04, PHP7, Laravel 5.4

Comment: А что в заголовке `Location` ответа?

Comment: Не называйте это юнит тестами.

Comment: @MikhailVaysman хорошо

Comment: @КапитанФлинт для юнит тестирования достаточно phpunit и все.

Comment: @DmitriySimushev как посмотреть?

Comment: Я, увы, не знаю, что за класс (`Tests\TestCase`) вы расширяете. Но в целом, вам надо посмотреть что из себя представляет объект `$response`. Там обязательно должны хранится заголовки ответа

Comment: @DmitriySimushev там мешанина всего и вся. Прежде чем Вас спросить как посмотреть я сделал `dump()`, ничего толкового не увидел и написал комментарий, думал Вы знаете

Comment: @КапитанФлинт посмотрите, что вернет `$response->headers->get('Location')`. Думаю это будет неплохой отправной точкой

Comment: @DmitriySimushev `http://localhost/login` там О_о откуда-то вообще непонятно. Если пробую вызывать `$response = $this->get( 'https://ya.ru' );`, то `$response->headers->get('Location')` выводит `https://ya.ru/login`. Это как так-то? Почему логин-то, таких и роутов-то нет у нас, не говоря уж про Яндекс

Comment: Следующий шаг: понять, кто выдает редирект. Скорее всего, это Laravel. А вот редирект при запросе к `ya.ru` действительно интересен. Есть у меня такое чувство, что сам запрос уходит к вашему локальному Laravel, но вот почему так происходит -- я не знаю.

Comment: @DmitriySimushev да даже если Laravel выдаёт, почему на `/login` то? :)) у нас нет такого роута, есть `/authorization`, `'/login` вообще неясно откуда берётся

Comment: Наверное, что-то из подключенных модулей добавляет этот маршрут. Мой хрустальный шар немного поломался, поэтому я не спец в дистанционной отладке

Comment: @DmitriySimushev понял, спасибо :))) чините шар :))

Comment: @DmitriySimushev роут `/login` есть в админке. Таким образом вместо домена, который я передаю, Ларавел кидает запрос на свой домен и редиректит, как задано, на `/login`, но не на себя, не на `http://admin.dev`, а почему-то на `/login` домена, который мы передаём