# PHPUnit and routes test

Tags: php, phpunit, testng

Я хочу протестировать роуты сайта с помощью PHPUnit. В частности, интересует статус ответа и тип контента. В официальной документации ничего об этом не нашёл. Подскажите какие-либо средства тестирования роутов, или, если PHPUnit это позволяет, подскажите где об этом почитать. Гуглю второй день, везде инфа по использованию PHPUnit через Laravel, но в Laravel у меня [свои проблемы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/703994/%D0%A2%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B2-laravel). В своё время юзал Mocha для проекта на Node.js, но сейчас не хотел бы его использовать.

Почему PHPUnit? Потому что по сути нужно юнит-тестирование, тестирование роутов - это некий начальный этап "до-юнит" тестирования, и хотелось бы сделать всё через один инструмент. Спасибо.

Comment: Вот [любопытная статья](https://blog.cloudflare.com/using-guzzle-and-phpunit-for-rest-api-testing/) на эту тему. **TL;DR**
Используется мощь GuzzleHttp клиента для хождения из тестов и проверка ответа "ручек".

Comment: Благодарю, как раз то что нужно.